# CSS Replace Text

Tags: css

```
<div class='d-flex align-items-center'>
    <img style="width: 16px;" class="mr-2" src="IMAGE.PNG"/>

    https://google.ca/
</div>
```

I need https://google.ca/ replaced with TEXT

I have not found a way to replace a text like this with another element in the div.

Comment: IMAGE.PNG is DYNAMIC so it changes..

Comment: CSS is for styling content, not content manipulation.

Comment: CSS is not content aware, you will need to use JS or something else.